Joint Trajectory Controller misses subscriber callback
I tested the Joint Trajectory Controller (JTC) on the UR10 robot in simulation and encountered a rare bug with the controller subscriber (joint_command_subscriber_) associated with the \joint_trajectory topic. Occasionally, the callback bound to the subscriber is not triggered, despite there being no apparent reason for this behavior.
After further testing, I confirmed that the issue lies with the callback not being called. I suspect the ROS 2 middleware might not be triggering the callback for unknown reasons. Since all nodes are running on the same machine, I don't believe the issue is related to packet loss or network problems. This bug is difficult to replicate as it occurs very infrequently.
Do you have any insights into why this might be happening? Could it be related to a configuration issue in the controller manager that’s causing this bug?
P.S. I am using ROS 2 Humble.
